# is graph database supported on django???? I can only find relational database

Tags: django, database, computer-science

I can't find any django framework for graph database. anyone knows one?

Answer (score 2):

Django out of the box doesn't support graph databases but there is a plugin called https://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel that allows you to use django in parallel with neo4j graph database. You will still need to use traditional databases or nosql databases like mongodb (with django-nonrel) for using django's auth, permissioning system etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) graph database with [neo4django](https://neo4django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).